# Python pyqt5 sending signal with default arguments AND additional arguments

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Right now I'm connecting a function to a signal:

```
table.cellClicked.connect(self.cellClick)
```

and I can access the `row` and `column` arguments from the `cellClicked` signal by simply using them as arguments

```
def cellClick(self, row, column):
    print("row, column: " + str(row) + ", " + str(column))
```

However, I want to send in an argument with it:

```
table.cellClicked.connect(lambda: self.cellClick(idx))
```

but if I do this, I can't access the `row` and `column` variables.

How do I send in additional arguments while also allowing for access to those variables?

Comment: Use `table.cellClicked.connect(lambda row, column, new_arg=idx: self.cellClick(row, column, new_arg))`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you! Your other answer didn't show up on google for some reason, looked for a while